# Can I tell Mylyn's context to be inclusive by default?

Tags: java, eclipse, task, mylyn

When I create a new task in Mylyn and activate it, all the resources in the package explorer become excluded by default from the new context and I have to manually select one by one all the resources I want to be included. Is there any way to tell Mylyn to be inclusive by default and exclude by hand what I don't want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that way is not possible.

But when you are in the e.g. package view and a task is activated, you can deactivate the task focused view with an click on [image].

Answer (score 1):

You can open feature request in https://bugs.eclipse.org

But please add some more information.

What do you expect?

do you want that we add

1. all selected file in the package view
2. all open editors
3. ...

For me 2. is the right way. Actual I add the open editors to the content wit a click in the title.